# Canvas Mouse Event in Graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, interactive

I've made a simple graphing function (ultimately will be used for stocks) and the one thing I'm having trouble with is how to make it so that when the mouse goes over a point on the graph, the data for that point is shown. Here's my code:

```
var y = [100,101,103,110,107,109]
var hy = 500;
var hw = (9/10)*hy;
var ny = [];
function newy(){
  ny = [];
  for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    ny.push(y[i]-getmin(y));
  }
  return ny;
}

window.onload = function() {
  newy();
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i=0; i < y.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(optx(i), opty(i));
      ctx.fillText(y.length-i-1, optx(i), hy);
      ctx.fillText(y[i], 0, opty(i));
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    for (var k=0; k < y.length; k++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(optx(k), opty(k),4,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}

function getmax(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(null,array);
}

function getmin(array) {
  return Math.min.apply(null,array);
}

function opty(i){
  return ((hw-hw*(ny[i])/(getmax(ny)))+(1/20)*hw);
}

function optx(i){
  return ((hw)*((i)/(ny.length-1))+(1/20)*hw);
}
```

I basically just want it so that mousing over a point on the graph displays the corresponding i value and the corresponding y[i] value. I have seen that I may need an event listener, but I didn't really understand. I'd appreciate any help! Here's the link to the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sanoziq/edit?html,css,js,output